# Dynamically changing log level in log4j version 1 and bridge to version 2

Tags: log4j, jmx, mbeans

I'm currently working on an application which wants to dynamically change the log level of a next java application (is running on the localhost). This external application uses log4j version 1.2.16. I want to use jmx, find all "LoggerConfigAdminMBean" and change level.

In specification (visit https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/jmx.html) is mentioned that it is possible with the log4j 2.

Because I do not want to do much changes in the external application, so I only changed log4j1.2.16.jar by log4j1.2bridge.jar (visit https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/index.html). But the result of this change is empty list of LoggerConfigAdminMBean.

Is the Jmx MBeans feature completely activated by using log4j 1.2 bridge jar and is there some way to get list of LoggerConfigAdminMBean full or is it possible only by migration from log4j1 to log4j2 version?

Thank you very much for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use these 2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And adapt log4j.properties, which must be placed in the project´s classpath. See: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties